# Android List View on Click position

Tags: android

I have a view where rows are being added through list view. The list item has following horizontally:
Checkbox   -Checkbox,
Item Name    - textView,
minus button -  Imagebutton,
quantity    - textview,
add button. - Imagebutton

I need to update quantity based on add or minus click. I am able to get the add button position through getTag(), but unable to get the corresponding quantity to update it.Below is the adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> mListItems;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    ItemDBAdapter itemDB;
    ViewHolder holder;
    int a =1;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> arrayList){

        mContext=context;
        mListItems=arrayList;
        mContext=context;
        //get the layout inflater
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


      private static class ViewHolder {

             TextView itemName,quantity;
                CheckBox checkbox;
                ImageButton addBtn,minusBtn;



        }
      @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            // create a ViewHolder reference


            //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
            if (convertview == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();


                convertview = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);



               /* holder.itemName=new TextView(mContext);
                holder.checkbox=new CheckBox(mContext);
                holder.quantity=new TextView(mContext);
                holder.addBtn=new ImageButton(mContext);
                holder.minusBtn=new ImageButton(mContext)*/;

                holder.itemName = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                holder.addBtn = (ImageButton) convertview.findViewById(R.id.add);
                holder.minusBtn = (ImageButton) convertview.findViewById(R.id.minus);
                holder.quantity = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
                holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
                holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
                holder.minusBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
                holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                holder.quantity.setTag(position);
                holder.addBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
                holder.addBtn.setOnClickListener(addBtnClick);
                holder.addBtn.setTag(position);
                //holder.minusBtn.setOnClickListener(minusBtnClick);
                holder.minusBtn.setTag(position);

                // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
                convertview.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
            }

            //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
            String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);

            if (stringItem != null) {
                if (holder.itemName != null) {
                    //set the item name on the TextView
                    holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
                }
      }

            //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
            return convertview;

        }


         private OnClickListener addBtnClick = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stube
                int b = (Integer) v.getTag();
                a = a + 1;
                holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(a));

            }
        };



}
```

Since the quantity is not clickable, I am unable to get the particular position to update quantity. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: `holder.quantity.setText(String.valueof(a))` a is an int. why is quantity not clickable?

Comment: Thanks for the input Raghunandan. I have used above only to set text(Typo error while posting). Its not working. I can get correct position of add button clicked but quantity is not being updated.

Comment: if quantity is say 1 then you click the button in the row you need to make it 2?

Comment: yes..and similarly when minus is clicked quantity should decrement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

In `onClick`

```
private OnClickListener addBtnClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = (View) v.getParent();
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            int value = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
            value=value+1; 
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }
    };
```

Edit: It is better to use a ViewHolder for smooth scrolling and performance

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Raghunandan. Its working but only on first click. When I click first time its changing value from 1 to 2, but on second click, its not working.Value remains 2.

Comment: @Gaurav try the edit now no need to set tag. if it helps don't forget to accept and upvote the answer

Comment: @Gaurav similarly for minus just decrement the value and set it to textview

Comment: Apologies for delayed response. Got some issue. Unfortunately its not working. Getting null point exception if I remove tag. Also I debugged original scenario (with tag on) and it seems that we need to set back the tag of addbtn to new changed value. Tried doing that but not working. Still stuck in issue.

Comment: @Gaurav you don't need a tag at all. when you click the button control goes to on click listener. there you the paren view and initialize textview . get hte text incerement the value and set the text back to the textview. i don't see any reason why it won't work i tried it before posting here. update question and post the stack trace

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I commented a line accidentally(while making changes). Cleaned up the code and ran again. Working like charm. As always my hours long struggle came to end with your response. Thanks  for everything and being there when I am stuck. Hopefully I will learn Android a bit quickly under your guidance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In if(convertView==null) block just get reference of views and setTag to them, in else part get previous tag. Apply all other things after else

change your code something like this....

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        // create a ViewHolder reference


        //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
        if (convertview == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            convertview = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder.itemName = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.addBtn = (ImageButton) convertview.findViewById(R.id.add);
            holder.minusBtn = (ImageButton) convertview.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            holder.quantity = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);



            // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
            convertview.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
        }

         holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
                            holder.minusBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
            holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(a));

            holder.addBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
            holder.addBtn.setOnClickListener(addBtnClick);
                        //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
        String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);

        if (stringItem != null) {
            if (holder.itemName != null) {
                //set the item name on the TextView
                holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
            }
  }

        //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
        return convertview;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kettu. I tried Raghunandan response above and it worked.

Comment: Cool.. you got what you wanted.